# Dolphin on SFTP "Communication with the local password server failed"

Tags: kubuntu, sftp, dolphin

Apparently every once in a while I get this weird "Communication with the local password server failed" error when trying to access SFTP via dolphin, while Terminal access still works.

While a reboot can temporarily fix that is there a way to fix it permanently or without reboot, like restarting that "Password Server" thing?